# Are used tires valuable?

Tags: tires, old-cars

I'm in the process of having my 1994 Corolla being picked up for recycling.  Currently the car is equipped with relatively unused winter tires with excellent tread.
Are used winter tires valuable? Should I consider paying the $30 to have someone replace them with the summer tires and look into selling the winters?
I can't be sure how many KMs were driven with the tires on, and the rims are moderately rusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine if the tires are valuable in your area (depending on location the value can vary wildly) call a couple places that buy back used tires and see what the average payment is for them.

In my area used tires cost to buy a used tire is from $25 (USD) and up per tire.

If the car is going to the recyclers why would it matter if the car had any tires on it at all?

My guesstimate would be that if you have to put *some* tires on it before going to the recycler then the costs/return will not work out in your favor.

Comment: The recycling program in the area requires that the car is not stripped of certain parts, including tires.  My guess is the tow truck coming to collect the car is not a flat bed.

Comment: @PaulBelardi I would hazard a guess to say that unless your winter tires are fabulously expensive, then it won't be worth your time and effort to swap out the tires

Comment: I once sold used tires on ebay.  I had bought a car that had all season tires, with reasonable amount of tread left, and I wanted to put performance tires on it.  I sold the old ones on ebay.  I didn't make much money off it though, but I did get the tires to someone else who could use them.

Comment: @PaulBelardi, even with a flat bed lorry they would need tyres on (they don’t want scraping the bed with suspension components or the rims). However, I once scrapped the car, but kept the set of wheels (rims and tyres, for the price of $50 total, including the spare). I just had to come by the recycler afterwards and pick up the wheels they dismounted for me before scrapping the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually put a free ad in a local web site - think kijiji or craigslist - to find out the "value".  I'm pretty sure that if the tires are useable, the scrap yard will resell them.

A set of 4 "almost new" winter tires should be worth something, but you might have to hang on to them until fall.  Not a lot of demand for them at this time of year (in the northern hemisphere, anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not worth paying someone to do it - as the value of old tyres isn't great, but if you do it yourself you could make a small amount of money from it.